# scraping content using selenium not working

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, python-3.5

I am trying to login to [this website](https://m.adidas.com/us/myaccount-create-or-login) using selenium. So I have imported the web driver and for sending the login information to that page I have also imported the Keys.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

This I used to prepare the selenium,

```
chromedriver = "chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get("https://m.adidas.com/us/myaccount-create-or-login")
```

I have made the browser to wait until the page loads using "implicitly wait function"

The user name column in the website has HTML content like this,

```html
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="* EMAIL" data-placeholder="* Email" maxlength="50" class="textinput required trimspace" name="username" id="username">
```

And for password it has

```html
<input type="password" placeholder="* PASSWORD" data-placeholder="* Password" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" name="password" value="" class="textinputpw required" id="password">
```

I have found the id's of the two elements with the above code and then I wrote this code to send the personal info

```
username1 = browser.find_element_by_id("username")
password1 = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
username1.send_keys(email.get()) # Used a gui entry box so why email.get()
password1.send_keys(password.get())
```

But the above code is not sending the info I don't know why it is? Could you help me with this please?

I have tried sending the keys using x path also. Printed the page source to check the website produces 403 Access denied error but that is not in my case.

I am new to this kindly bare if anything is wrong

**EDIT** :- My Try:

```
username1 = browser.find_element_by_id("username")
browser.switch_to.frame(username1)
password1 = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
browser.switch_to.frame(password1)
username1.send_keys(email.get()) # Used a gui entry box so why email.get()
password1.send_keys(password.get())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements you are trying to reach are inside an `IFRAME`.

```
<iframe id="loginaccountframe" class="sso-iframe" src="https://cp.adidas.com/web/eCom/en_US/loadsignin?target=account" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

You will need to switch into the IFRAME before you can see them.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames

Comment: I have tried adding browser.switch_to.frame(username1) after the id(I refrred another satck overflow answer and that alos prints element not found exception could you explain more. I referred that tutorial too.. I am new kindly help me

Comment: You didn't mention that you had tried switching to the frame. This is an important detail. The best way to get help is to explain what all you have tried and provide the code you used and what the result was. I just tried simply switching to the iframe and entering an email and password and it worked just fine. You should try again and if it doesn't work, post the code you tried (in your question) and what the result was... exception message, etc.

Comment: Could you please post your code so that I can see what I am missing?(I requested this since you told it is working for you) I will learn from your codee

Comment: You probably should read some basic HTML tutorials, especially some about frames/IFRAMEs and how you interact with them using Selenium. An `IFRAME` is an HTML tag. Selenium can't see inside one until you switch the context to it. The code you have is trying to switch context to the username element and not the `IFRAME`.

Comment: I don't have python... I wrote it in Java. It's simple enough that you should be able to write it yourself after reading the docs I linked and some basic tutorials.

Comment: It is ok I have bad English knowledge I just need to learn even Java code will be sufficient for me. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, I used this code, browser.switch_to.frame("loginaccountframe")    before the getting ID then how to switch back to window for regular scrapping?? Thank you

Comment: The answer is in the link that I posted.

Comment: I have fixed those exceptions Thank you will learn more from you :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually [@JeffC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2386774/jeffc) is right, there is an `iframe`. So before finding element inside an `iframe` you have to switch that `iframe`.

As you have mentioned in comment as :-

> I have tried adding browser.switch_to.frame(username1)

You're actually switching `username1` element to supposing `iframe` element which is wrong.

You need to find `iframe` element separately as other element you are trying to find and then switch to that iframe element. But here you can switch to `iframe` by using its `id` as below :-

```
browser.switch_to.frame("loginaccountframe")

#now do your login stuff inside iframe
username1 = browser.find_element_by_id("username")
username1.send_keys(email.get()) # Used a gui entry box so why email.get()

password1 = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
password1.send_keys(password.get())

#now after doing all stuff inside iframe you need to switch back to default content for further steps 
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```